# Angular 7 Typescript. Create variable that can be directly accessed in Chrome Console

Tags: angular, typescript

I wonder if it is possible to create a variable that can be directly accessed in the Chrome Console so that I can use it to debug, etc?

For example, in angularJS javascript, if I define `v = 1`, I can use it in the Chrome Console like `a = v+1; console.log(a)`, which returns `2`. I just would like to do the same thing in angular 7 typescripts. However, if I do the same thing in `.ts` file, then the error message is `Cannot find name 'v'` and my console cannot find `v`.

If this is not feasible in typescript, is there any debugging plugin can do a similar thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global variables are assigned to window object:
`(window as any).globalItem = 'test';`

Then it will be accessible in console, however this is a bad practice and I never had a need to do that, I suggest to just stick to break points. Also this is unrelated to Angular or TypeScript and is just plain JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure why this is not a good practice. This is simply for debugging or developing code. When going to production, the public global variable will not be there anyways.